# jQuery.getScript loads javascript file before DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax

Using ajax to load my content dynamically. I need to load a javascript file after I click on a button:

```
<a id="element" href="http://example.com/test">button</a>
```

But the script below loads the javascript file before the DOM has been loaded.
How can I solve this?

```
$("#element").click(function () {
  jQuery.getScript("example.com/jsfile.js?ver=0.9");  
});
```

screenshot of firebug: http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/1630/4mu7.png

The 1st row is the loaded javascript file that's called via the above function and the 3rd row is the page that's being loaded.

Comment: Are you clicking the button before the dom is loaded?

Comment: Yes, how do you manage to trigger this function before the DOM is ready?

Comment: When you click the `a#element`, it would go to another page `http://example.com/test`.

Comment: no the button is being clicked after dom load. 
@ khan, yes it's going to that page without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use document's `readyState` property:

```
$("#element").click(function () {
    if(document.readyState === "complete")
        jQuery.getScript("example.com/jsfile.js?ver=0.9");
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState

Answer (score 0):

Working `JSBin` - http://jsbin.com/uJUBAru/1/edit

Jquery approach use document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#element").click(function () {
    $.getScript("example.com/jsfile.js?ver=0.9").done(function(script, textStatus) {
        console.log( textStatus );
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        console.log( 'error' );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: the button loads a div content of "example.com/test" via ajax to the maincontent div of the homepage "example.com". However Firebug's net panel is reporting in the waterfall graph that the javascript is being loaded before the page "http://example.com/test" is loaded.

Comment: @Eric : look at my jsbin http://jsbin.com/uJUBAru/1/edit ..this may give you some clue

Comment: Thaks Amith, but the problem only is that the javascript is being loaded before DOM (example.com/test).
Please see screenshot above in my question

Answer (score 0):

I've set a timeout for the function. Now the page loads and after 5 sec the javascript loads.
Although this is a solution, it's not very safe.

Any other suggestions?

```
    $("#element").click(function ()
{setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery.getScript("example.com/jsfile.js?ver=0.9");
}, 5000);

});
```